# template class with parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Class in my program should use fftw library for image processing. The class should have possibilities for work with float and double types. For this purpose i implement following construction:

```
class MyClass
{
...
public:
    template <class T> 
    class FftTypes{ };
...
}
```

and include *.inl file in header file "MyClass.h" where i write

```
template <>
class MyClass::FftTypes<float>
    {
    private:
        typedef fftwf_plan fft_plan;
    public:
        typedef fftwf_complex fft_complex;

        static fft_complex* fft_malloc(int size
    ....
    }
```

and similar class for double type:

```
template <> 
class MyClass::FftTypes<double>
{
private:
    typedef fftw_plan fft_plan;

public:
    typedef fftw_complex fft_complex;

    static fft_complex* fft_malloc(int size)
```

Today i find out that i should add function in class MyClass that get as parameter fft_complex type. I surf the INTERNET and different sources but i could not find the way how i can do it? do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does it take a parameter, like void myFunction( fft_complex* ) ?

Comment: I see no problem in adding function to `MyClass`, which is not even template class. What's wrong with `void MyClass::foo(fft_complex complex)`? Or you want `fft_complex` to be a template parameter?

Comment: kiss-o-matic> not it doesnt take any parameters. 
Oleg Andriyanov>if i just add MyClass::foo(fft_complex complex then i get an error message that fft_complex unknown type. include inl file placed after class ending, that is the main problem

Comment: Don't put it in the .inl file then. If you have declarations that need to be visible they should be in the header.

Comment: Alan Stokes > i know it but I'm interesting can i do it with inl file or not